# under which conditions is process orphaned in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, signals

I  have a network device based on `FreeBSD 7`. For some reason, sometimes `/usr/sbin/cli`(executable which provides vendor-specific CLI) and its child-process are orphaned(alive, but parent is `init`):

```
# ps -p 7173,7175,1 -o pid,ppid,start,user,command
  PID  PPID STARTED USER COMMAND
    1     0 26Apr17 root /packages/mnt/jbase/sbin/init --
 7173     1 31Dec17 test   cli -c traceroute 10.10.98.8 as-number-lookup; quit
 7175  7173 31Dec17 test   /usr/sbin/traceroute -JA 10.10.98.8
#
```

As seen above, `cli`(process status is `idle`) was started a month ago. It was started by `sshd`(runs under user `root`). What signal is sent by `sshd` process to `cli` process when SSH client time-outs or disconnects? Is `cli` process able to ignore this signal? I tried to analyze this with `truss` by executing `truss -f -p <cli PID>` and then disconnecting the SSH client, but no signals were sent to `cli`. Then I took a step back and executed `truss -f -p <sshd: freebsd@notty (sshd) PID>`(parent process of `cli` process) and killed the SSH client. This provides the following debug output:

```
1565: select(13,{ 3 5 7 10 12 },{ },0x0,0x0)    = 1 (0x1)
1565: sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGCHLD },{ })    = 0 (0x0)
1565: sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)          = 0 (0x0)
1565: clock_gettime(4,{ 5568.946095396 })       = 0 (0x0)
1565: read(3,"\M^]G)\M-=[\M^Y\M-Z\M-pD\M^O\M^]"...,16384) = 60 (0x3c)
1565: clock_gettime(13,{ 1517409641.000000000 }) = 0 (0x0)
1565: getpid()                                  = 1565 (0x61d)
1565: socket(PF_LOCAL,SOCK_DGRAM,0)             = 8 (0x8)
1565: fcntl(8,F_SETFD,FD_CLOEXEC)               = 0 (0x0)
1565: connect(8,{ AF_UNIX "/var/run/logpriv" },106) ERR#13 'Permission denied'
1565: connect(8,{ AF_UNIX "/var/run/log" },106) = 0 (0x0)
1565: sendto(8,"<38>Jan 31 14:40:41 sshd[1565]: "...,106,0x0,NULL,0x0) = 106 (0x6a)
1565: close(8)                                  = 0 (0x0)
1565: clock_gettime(13,{ 1517409641.000000000 }) = 0 (0x0)
1565: getpid()                                  = 1565 (0x61d)
1565: socket(PF_LOCAL,SOCK_DGRAM,0)             = 8 (0x8)
1565: fcntl(8,F_SETFD,FD_CLOEXEC)               = 0 (0x0)
1565: connect(8,{ AF_UNIX "/var/run/logpriv" },106) ERR#13 'Permission denied'
1565: connect(8,{ AF_UNIX "/var/run/log" },106) = 0 (0x0)
1565: sendto(8,"<38>Jan 31 14:40:41 sshd[1565]: "...,74,0x0,NULL,0x0) = 74 (0x4a)
1565: close(8)                                  = 0 (0x0)
1565: geteuid()                                 = 1001 (0x3e9)
1565: unlink("/tmp/ssh-2A9AWQYCLZ/agent.1565")  = 0 (0x0)
1565: rmdir(0x804024c40)                        = 0 (0x0)
1565: process exit, rval = 255
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a FreeBSD user, but this is basically a Unix question...

A process is orphaned whenever it's parent process dies. This happens all the time, and is not normally a problem. A parent dying does not automatically kill the child.

In the specific case of SSH (and telnet, etc), the shell would normally receive SIGHUP when the connection is lost. It's that that kills the shell, not being orphaned. If your custom CLI chooses to handle SIGHUP in a non-standard way (i.e. not die) then anything could happen.